"Baking" grain texture onto object?
I am trying to develop a procedural animation system that mimics 2D in Blender 3D using curves and want to mimic 2D art styles by having grain shading on an object, but have it adjust to the object's curve/scale changing, for instance, but not change it if the object is stationary (or better yet, only change it when I want it too - frame-by-frame).
I'm using a thin 3D plane basically with a flat shader to achieve the basic vector 2D-appearing shapes while maintaining the flexibility of 3D shaders, etc.
Basically have the light baked on for particular frames and not for others, and looking for the most flexible way to do this.
I'd like the shading/grain subtlety changed only when the object is moved/morphed.


Naturally in 3D of course, the light is going to subtlety changed and what I've noticed is every frame the grain will change a little - not allowing the illusion of a 2D animated object.
Hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance!

Hi, jon .. welcome .. An illustration would help this make more sense :) ...  you can embed screen grabs into an edit of your post with the tools provided. In particular, that would help us to see exactly what you mean by 'grain'.

OK, I updated it with examples.

Thanks. .. Love the artwork :)

Thanks so much, Robin. :)
